How Can I run Android SDK upgrade assistant in IntelliJ?
Google has a page where it suggests trying the Android SDK upgrade assistant when upgrading target SDK.
https://developer.android.com/build/sdk-upgrade-assistant
Thought I'd try it, but I'm running IntelliJ, and when I go into tools, there's no upgrade assistant there?
Is it possible to use it from IntelliJ, or am I missing something else?
Pointers appreciated.

Unfortunately, it is not possible :( Upgrade assistant is essentially a plugin. But if you'll go to marketplace and search for it, it doesn't exist there.
On the other side, in Android Studio, there is that plugin in installed list. More than that, it is marked as "bundled". It means that Studio is delivered with it and it is a part of default installation.
There is also an answer in Idea issue tracker, from IntelliJ maintainer. He also tells that Upgrade Assistant is exclusive for Android Studio

Wow, that's unfortunate. I don't get why it's studio-only, they both are made by Jetbrains.

well, it is interesting. Although studio indeed built on top of IntelliJ, I believe that Google maintain studio itself. Also, there is license agreement and it prohibits usage of Android SDK (for example) for 3rd party developers outside development for Android platform. I'm not expert here, but maybe Upgrade Assistant somehow uses SDK and that why is closed-source and belongs only to google.
